# How to change this merge() method for a Multi-Value Register CRDT implementation?

Tags: java, merge, crdt

I have the following problem: In this simple implementation of a MVR-CRDT the merge() method should add all values that are not null to the merged replica. For that to happen i used a for loop which iterates through both ArrayLists. At every index where a value is present it compares the vector clocks and overwrites the value of the highest clock at said index. It seems to not be working as intended. I would be glad if somebody can point out the problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MVR_CRDT{

    //variables
    static int size;
    private ArrayList<Integer> vectorClock;
    private ArrayList<Object> values;
    
    //constructor
    public MVR_CRDT(int size) {
        this.vectorClock = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(size, 0));
        this.values = new ArrayList<Object>(Collections.nCopies(size, null));
    }    
    
    //sets a value and increments its corresponding vector clock
    public void setValue(int index, Object value) {
        //check if value is different
        if (value != this.values.get(index)){
            this.vectorClock.set(index, this.vectorClock.get(index) + 1);
            this.values.set(index, value);
            //goes over the other indexes and empties their value
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                while (i != index){
                    this.values.set(i, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //the second replica merges into the first
    public static void merge(MVR_CRDT first, MVR_CRDT second){
            //loops through the ArrayList
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                //if there is a value to be merged
                if (second.values.get(i) != null){
                    first.vectorClock.set(i, max(first.vectorClock.get(i), second.vectorClock.get(i)));
                    first.values.set(i, second.values.get(i));
                }
            }
    }
    
    private static Integer max(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
        return null;
    }

    //gets the value at index position of a replica
    public Object getValue(int index) {
        return this.values.get(index);
    }

    public Integer getVector(int index) {
        return this.vectorClock.get(index);
    }

    //prints the replica
    public void query() {
        System.out.println("Vector Clock: " + this.vectorClock.toString());
        System.out.println("Values: " + this.values.toString() + "\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MVR_CRDT Alice = new MVR_CRDT(3);
        MVR_CRDT Bob = new MVR_CRDT(3);
        MVR_CRDT Charlie = new MVR_CRDT(3);

        Alice.setValue(0, "Hello");
        Alice.setValue(0, "Hello"); //to show that Alices counter does not increase
        System.out.println("Alice's replica: ");
        Alice.query();

        Bob.setValue(1, 12312);
        System.out.println("Bob's replica: ");
        Bob.query();

        // Charlie.setValue(2, false);

        merge(Alice, Bob);
        System.out.println("Alice's replica after merging: ");
        Alice.query();

        // System.out.println(Bob.getValue(1) + " , " + Bob.getVector(1));

    }

}
```

Output after merge expected:

`Vector Clock: [1, 1, 0] Values: [Hello, 12312, null]`

Main method output:

```
Alice's replica: 
Vector Clock: [1, 0, 0]
Values: [Hello, null, null]

Bob's replica:
Vector Clock: [0, 1, 0]
Values: [null, 12312, null]

Alice's replica after merging:
Vector Clock: [1, 0, 0]
Values: [Hello, null, null]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, several improvements can be done. I start with the one you asked for, so you can stop after that:

Your method `merge` uses the static variable `size` as stop criterion in the `for` loop, that is never explicitly initialized, so it is implicitly initialized to `0` - the loop in `merge` never does a single pass, so your output shows an unmodified `Alice`.

But even if it would use a "better" size, like e.g. `first.vectorClock.size()` it would not output the correct result - but a different one:

```text
Alice's replica after merging: 
Vector Clock: [1, null, 0]
Values: [Hello, 12312, null]
```

This is because your `max` method always returns `null`.  I would recommend that you use a built in `max` method like `Integer.max(int, int)`. Then your expected result will be output.

---

And now for some other findings (you could stop reading, your original problem is solved):
Please use an established naming convention when you post code here, for Java this is in the Java Language Specification, chapter 6. Names, section [6.1. Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1) (it starts after the long nested list there, written in italic).

So for your class name that should be `MvrCrdt` or maybe better `MultiValueRegisterCRDT` - or even longer?
Your instances `Alice` and `Bob` should start with a lowercase letter and be `alice` and `bob`.

Your code leftovers and commented code should be removed, before posting here.

*Declarations:* your member fields do not need to know the implementation of the list, it's sufficient to use `List<Integer>` and `List<Object>`, use `ArrayList<>` in the constructor only with the `new` operator!

As you never reassign the member fields `vectorClock` and `values`,  you should make them `final`.

*Constructor:* You don't need to specify the type that the list stores on the assignment, it's sufficient to have `this.vectorClock = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size, 0));`

*Method `setValue`*: You have the same issue with `size` in your `setValue` method, replace it with `this.values.size()`.

In the `while` loop inside your `for` loop the values of `i` and `index` never change inside the `while` loop, so you should replace the `while` with an `if` or you change the loop-body. Otherwise you will have an endless loop, if the loop is ever entered! For now you didn't face this problem, since the outer `for` loop never was entered.

*Method `merge`*: That method should neither be `static` nor take two parameters. It always modifies the first input, so it could as well just take the object to merge into the current instance and manipulate `this` instead of `first`:

```java
public void merge(MultiValueRegisterCrdt other) {
  //loops through the ArrayList
  for (int i = 0; i < this.vectorClock.size(); i++) {
    //if there is a value to be merged
    if (other.values.get(i) != null) {
      this.vectorClock.set(i, Integer.max(this.vectorClock.get(i), other.vectorClock.get(i)));
     this.values.set(i, other.values.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

With that modification you would have to use it so: `alice.merge(bob);`

*Method `query`:* you could replace this with an override of `toString` like:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "MultiValueRegisterCrdt{" +
      "vectorClock=" + vectorClock +
      ", values=" + values +
      '}';
}
```

Then you can use it like `System.out.println("Alice's replica: \n" + alice);`

Comment: Thank you for the time @cyberbrain. All of your advice has lead to a properly working code. I will try my best to abide to the established naming conventions of any language in the future.